# Bounce/Ease animation for nav bar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, navbar

Anyone knows how this website bounces their nav bar to the top when the user is not at the top of the page?

http://whois.domaintools.com/

This is what I got so far.

```
if(scrollTop > 0){
                console.log(scrollTop);
                if(nav.hasClass('navbar-static-top')){
                    nav.removeClass('navbar-static-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                }
            } else {
                if(nav.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')){
                    nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-static-top');
                }
            }
```

This works but I cant seem to get the bounce effect:(
Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks everyone:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS `transition-timing-function` property has a value of `ease-in`.

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/os1Ld8fj/1/

Comment: WOW THANKS ALOT YOURE AWESOME. I spent like the last three hours on this. thank you so much:))